# Раскрутка или продвижение сайта: как? что делать?

Tags: seo, продвижение, раскрутка

Я думаю этот вопрос будет интересным, а его ответы полезными для других посетителей сообщества.

И так, создал я сайт. `Тут важно упомянуть что домен новый, 1 месяц после регистрации всего прошло.` Разработан он по всем (на мой взгляд) необходимым требованиям/рекомендациям seo оптимизации: `уникальный title` для страниц с ключевым словом, `description`, `ключевые слова`, `микроразметка schema.org`, `open graph`, `адаптивный дизайн`.

На сайте публикуется уникальный контен(статьи), по 2-5 в день.

Зарегистрирован в яндекс.вебмастер, гугл поисковая консоль. Все найденные ошибки  в вебматсере устранены, никаких проблем с сайтом они не выявляют.

robots.txt, карта сайта xml, турбо-страницы - все есть и правильно работает.
Яндекс.метрика и гугл аналитика установлены.

**А что дальше?** На сайт из поиска в день заходит 1-2 чел. максимум... (только не понимаю как его находят, я сам нахожу его в поиске по запросу соответствующему title только на 5-той странице гугла).

Все страницы сайта в поиске есть, но по заголовку их не находит(кроме главной), по крайней мере их нет в первых 20(дальше не смотрел) страницах выдачи поиска.

Какие дальнейшие действия нужно предпринимать? Неужели просто публиковать материал на своем сайте и ждать того дня когда посетители начнут заходить из поисковиков? да и к тому времени большинство материала уже может быть не актуальным...

Поделитесь своим опытом, что нужно делать и как... Может я вообще делаю все неправильно? вот это может (неосознанность, а может не так) меня и пугает...

**P.S.** вариант с покупкой рекламы на сайт не рассматривается, интересно только  его естественное продвижение, без финансовых вложений

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваш веб-сайт представляет какой то бизнес, то очень важно определить **[Уникальное торговое предложение](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_selling_proposition)** для субъекта вашего бизнеса (производство, торговля, товар, услуги или что-то ещё). Уникальное торговое предложение (USP) относится к уникальной выгоде, предоставляемой компанией, услугой, продуктом или брендом, которая позволяет ему выделиться среди конкурентов. Википедия имеет русский вариант для USP, однако по моему скромному мнению английский вариант более описывающий.

Ключевые слова и фразы которые имеют отношение к USP вы можете анализировать на бесплатном онлайн инструменте **[Answer The Public](https://answerthepublic.com/)**. Полученные там результаты помогут вам определить намерения пользователей относительно ваших продуктов, услуг или субъектов ваших статей.

Далее вы можете создавать веб-страницы с содержанием в виду ответов для намерений пользователей. Там может быть важно создавать правильную иерархическую структуру веб-страницы с использованием элементов **[H heading](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp)**. Элемент H1 вероятно будет иметь название вашего веб-сайта или вашего бизнеса. Элемент H2 может иметь содержание в виде вопроса соответствующего намерениям пользователей, которые вы определили с помощью указанного выше инструмента. Далее вы создаете уникальное содержание, которое отвечает на вопрос. Там может быть полезным использование ниже стоящих элементов h для улучшения видимости структуры веб-страницы для пользователей. Им будет легче сразу же перейти к нужному разделу текста.

Например, если пользователи часто ищут информацию о плюсах и минусах вегетарианской пищи и вы опубликовали такую статью на вашем веб-сайте, то велика вероятность того что на эту статью будет большой органический трафик. 
То же самое может относиться, например, к запросу "Ремонт системы охлаждения автомобиля Вольво XC-60 в Вологде".

Answer (score 1):

вы на пятой странице с новым доменом потому как поисковики новичкам дают шанс где-то на 2-3 месяца. А потом суровая правда...

Продвижение вооще абстрактная штука. Если сайт классный, все равно нужно донести инфо людям.
Заведите группы в социалках, придумайте какой-то конкурс

Comment: уже есть группы в соц. сетях. но на них акцент не делаем, они просто есть, пустые, и созданы только для того чтобы домен быстрее попал в поиск.

Comment: не вкладывая на привлечение клиентов вы их не привлечете массово. Вот 1-2 человека в день и есть) Постеперенно, если контент качественный, будет прирост. Но ПОСТЕПЕННО!